# Colour Highlighting of SIMILAR or ALTERNATIVE blocks of Code

Tags: objective-c

Is there some way to highlight similar or alternative code blocks in xCode or alternative Obj-C program? At the attached picture you can quickly realise which block runs after another or which is an alternative (if-else). (The code on the picture is just example). It seems to be the task related to {}-counting, so I expect there is some implementation.
Actually, I could understand the FLOW of the code on the picture only after I highlighted it as you see.

[image]

Comment: this would be pretty cool

Comment: I use a version of TextMate2 that I patched to show tab guides, which serves a similar purpose. The patch isn't universal enough to submit though (only works with tabs, not with spaces). Still hoping TM2 will support it natively at some point.

It looks similar to this screenshot of jEdit: http://www.jedit.org/index.php?page=screenshot&image=29 jEdit (platform-independent, uses Java and works well on OS X) does support it natively, I added that there many years ago. Don't know of other Editors that have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is scope highlighting. Xcode does not do this to my knowledge. However, you can mouse over the code folding column to the left and see the scope briefly.

Comment: Wait for 5. It shows this in the same place in a better way without mouse over.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is kind of a non-answer, I originally wrote it as a comment. But it got too long, so I'm putting it here. Apologies in advance for avoiding the question. But I'm trying to address the problem *behind* the question…

If you have to color-code a method to understand it, **the method is too long.** [Extract methods](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) and give them meaningful names that clearly state their purpose (though not their implementation).

Here are rules-of-thumb I follow:

- If a method has many local variables, or a number of different indentations, first use [Extract Class](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) to pull the method into a new class that works as a function object. Then promote the local variables to ivars.
- Despite many who state the dangers, if an inner scope has one line, I omit the braces. This reduces the vertical distance of the code, which makes it more readable. Readability is more important. (But this may be risky if your code isn't covered by unit tests. So make sure the method is well-covered.)
- When I see braces inside a method, I try to extract that portion into another (well-named) method.
- Look for opportunities to extract the contents of `if` statements into predicate methods that express the *what* (burying the *how* inside the method).
- I try to keep methods under six lines. Any more than that, and I start eyeing it critically: Is it doing more than one thing? Is it operating at more than one level of abstraction?

For much, much more on these principles, I highly recommend [Clean Code episode 3](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-3/show).

Comment: Its an opinion, but i hate leaving out the braces. Add a line, or remove one, and you get trouble. Even more in a team environment. Plus, it gives the function a little 'air'. But i definitely agree with the 'function gets too long' bit.

Comment: Rob, "Braces always required" is a common coding standard for the reasons you state. With good unit test coverage, however, those reasons vanish. …What do you mean by 'air'?

Comment: I should also add that in a 5-line method, it's harder to make such a mistake.

Comment: by 'air' i mean a little breathing space around the statements, those help seeing code groups, in a similar way that horizontal indentation does.

Comment: Actually, I am learning, so the method above is not mine and I just wanted to understand it. Thanks for explaing me about the good practice.